# IMU gravity tracking

Tags: estimation, state-space, imu

I'm interested in tracking the gravity vector for a UAV supposing we don't have external input or GPS.

I think a solution to the problem is as a follows:

1. We have a past gravity direction vector which was correct.
2. We have a gyro which we use to update that gravity vector when angular movement is detected.
3. We assume the accelerometer reading consists of the gravity vector plus some noise which is caused by external input(ex control inputs, etc)

When the gyro sense movement we update 1 to give the direction of gravity in the body frame of the UAV, we then take a moving average of that reading against the new accelerometer reading. The accelerometer reading could also have a low pass filter applied to it.

Is there a better way to do this? I  the KF framework I suppose 1 would be the state, 2 would be the control and 3 would be the sensing step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search term you are looking for is "vertical gyro*".

You can do this by establishing a gravity vector that rotates per the IMU's gyro outputs on a 1:1 basis, with a gentle servo action to the IMU's gravity vector to zero out any error.

In a Kalman filter framework, you can model the system as one that has a zero average velocity with a very very high measurement error.  There's probably more compact ways to do it, but what I can think of off the top of my head has 5 to 7 states: three for velocity in x, y and z, and between two and four states for the angle (two if you can figure out how to just do tilt away from horizontal, three if you want to use Euler angles, and four if you want to use quaternions).

If you do a Kalman filter you'll end up with something that works like my more intuitive explanation in steady state, only a lot more complex.

You'll find that -- because you don't know position -- whatever solution you come up with will be a compromise between how fast the thing acquires vertical and how much tilt it acquires when your craft is doing fast, large-diameter turns.  The basic problem is that the thing only knows how to average the inertial gravity vector over a long term; when you establish a turn that starts taking as long to complete as your filter's time constant, then the centripetal acceleration from the turn will become less distinguishable from the real gravity vector.

---

*The first one I ever saw, in the late 1990's, was about as big as a football**, and had mechanical gyros, little bitty torquer motors, mechanical gyroscopes and potentiometers.

** American football